# Intermittantly can't edit Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus running over Windows7 64 Enterprise. While I work on an Excel spreadsheet, it will often refuse to let me edit a cell. I click in the formula bar but the editing cursor doesn't appear. When this problem occurs, I am then unable to edit any cells in the spreadsheet, or use the arrow keys to move to different cells. I can still use the mouse to select (but still not edit) other cells. I can restore my ability to edit cells (at least temporarily) by selecting/clicking on another (second) sheet/tab in my spreadsheet and then returning to the main sheet. Is there any way to stop this intermittent "no editing allowed" behavior by Excel?

Update: I have determined that this problem only occurs after having multiple Excel spreadsheet files open for several hours. If I close all current instances of Excel on my PC and then reopen Excel from scratch with the problem spreadsheet, this problem doesn't occur. I have decided that the problem is caused by some subtle memory leak or other bug that is "fixed" by opening a fresh copy of the the Excel program.

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have tried to edit your question anonymously (maybe not logged into account?)

Comment: This happened to me just now, I closed some of the open worksheets and it started working again. I was able to double click on a cell, (edit mode), and then I could type while the problem was happening...

Comment: Do  any of the workbooks you have open run macros? there might be something being triggered that is preventing editing until it is addressed. If there are any forms or pop-ups these can cause the behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: @JustinDoward Nope, the sheets don't have any macros or forms in them; they are just large and have a lot of cells with formulas pointing at other cells.

Answer (score 1):

I am copying OP's update from 2016 as a community answer to provide closure to what is technically still an unanswered question:

> I have determined that this problem only occurs after having multiple
> Excel spreadsheet files open for several hours. If I close all current
> instances of Excel on my PC and then reopen Excel from scratch with
> the problem spreadsheet, this problem doesn't occur. I have decided
> that the problem is caused by some subtle memory leak or other bug
> that is "fixed" by opening a fresh copy of the the Excel program.